# How to display facebook page like count in Prestashop (Smarty)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, smarty, prestashop

I have this code in PHP which works perfectly: http://pastebin.com/sgVFDMW8
However I have no idea how to implement it into the footer.tpl in my prestashop page.
I tried adding it in the FrontController, between {php}...{/php} tags, but no luck...

Would appreciate your help!

Comment: why not your just use the facebook api, where they will give you a plugin javascript code, and you place it in your footer.tpl file?

Comment: Because I want to show the count as part of custom text ("32,000 people followed us on facebook. What about you?")

Comment: What did you try with the FronController? Can you show us some code?

Comment: Added this: http://pastebin.com/FHVygaXw
Done that after reading: http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/123746-overriding-frontcontroller/

Comment: Found the solution and answered myself. Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, took me long time, and I had to dig deep into smarty (or at least - deeper than I wanted). Smarty is so unfriendly IMHO.

Here is the solution:
Out of the box, Smarty can't decode JSON objects, so:

1. Add this plugin: https://gist.github.com/tony-landis/31451
2. Assign the JSON object to a variable in the .tpl file like that: 
   {json url='http://www.something.com/json' assign=result}
3. Use this wherever you need in your .tpl file:
   {$result->name}

If you see the page break somewhere, turn smarty debugging on, or check your Apache error log.

Hope it will help someone else too :)

Answer (score 0):

So, this will work in Prestashop 1.5x

( Note : this exemple add the facebook page likes into the footer.tpl)

1- go to the file:

classes/controller/FrontController.php

add somewhere in the class this function:

```
public static function fbcount($idpage){
        $ch = curl_init("http://graph.facebook.com/$idpage");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $raw = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $data = json_decode($raw);
        return $data->likes;
}
```

2- then in the footer.tpl file you can use this:

```
{FrontController::fbcount('399888213399907')}
```

where the 399888213399907 is id of your page

enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but since my own answer doesn't change core files, I think my implementation is better.